# Interleaving "^" character in a string

Tags: python, string

I'm currently tasked with replacing `"SUPER MAN"` with `"S^U^P^E^R M^A^N"`.

I've tried `print("SUPER MAN".replace("" "", "^"))` but end up with `^S^U^P^E^R^ ^M^A^N^`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) method along with [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split).

First `split` `"SUPER MAN"` by a space to get:

```
words = "SUPER MAN".split()
["SUPER", "MAN"]
```

Then for each of those entries, separate each character with `"^"` using `join`:

```
new_words = map(lambda x: "^".join(x), words)
["S^U^P^E^R", "M^A^N"]
```

Then turn it back into one string separated by a space using `join`, and your resulting code is:

```
words = "SUPER MAN".split()
new_words = map(lambda x: "^".join(x), words)
print " ".join(new_words)
```

Output: `S^U^P^E^R M^A^N`

**What your code is doing:**

First, notice that the first parameter that you pass into `replace` is not a space, which is what you presumably intended for it be, but the expression `"" ""`, which is an implicit way of doing string concatenation.

Thus, `"SUPER MAN".replace("" "", "^")` becomes `"SUPER MAN".replace("", "^")`, which replaces each occurrence of `""` with `"^"`.

The result of such an operation may at first seem somewhat ill-defined, but in Python, since you can think of a string `s` as being equal to `"" + "".join(s) + ""`, replacing each occurrence of `""` with `"^"` would yield what you see: a `"^"` between each letter and a `"^"` on the ends.

Passing a `" "` as the first parameter to `replace` doesn't work, because it will replace spaces (specifically, the space in the middle) with `"^"`, so you'd get `"SUPER^MAN"`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I haven't researched enough on using the lambda function yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"(\w)(?=\w)", r"\1^", "SUPER MAN")
'S^U^P^E^R M^A^N'
```

For more on why that works: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

With sting manipulation you can use `.split()` to split to two words and then `.join()` to join it with the special character. To avoid having 'magic strings' perhaps assign a variable to the special character.

```
hero = "SUPER MAN"
word = hero.split()
special_char = "^"
```

There can be 2 ways to display the output `S^U^P^E^R M^A^N`

Method 1: using join each word with the special character.

```
print(special_char.join(word[0])
      + " "
      + special_char.join(word[1]))
```

Method 2: assign variables on each word separately, and then .join() with the special character

```
word_1 = special_char.join(word[0])
word_2 = special_char.join(word[1])

print(word_1, word_2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to trim the string "SUPER MAN" before passing it to replace()? And then you can always use a StringBuilder (assuming you're using Java) and then use DeleteCharAt() method to manually remove extra '^'.

Comment: He's using Python not Java. Second, his string is already trimmed.